# Minecraft Beta Server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I am trying to run a Bedrock Beta edition server for me and my friends. Is there a link to download a dedicated server for beta?
Stats:
[image: stats]

Answer (score -4):

**You can't make a server for Bedrock Beta.** **If you are talking about a server for snapshots there is no way to make one for Bedrock yet. Also to make a server you must pay money. You cannot just download one.** **Realms does cost money but also you can create a server with an actual address like** *mc.hive.com* **but you have to find a website to do that.** *Sometimes you can find websites that are free to use to create a server but most of the time you can't*

Comment: In that case is there a way to use viaversion and geyser on a PaperMC sever to accomplish this?

Comment: "Also to make a server you must pay money" this is horridly incorrect. do you by any chance mean "realms"? that is not what the user is asking about

Comment: Yeah, I can local host or use a free hosting service.

Comment: You can download server software. The minecraft website literally has entirely free dedicated server downloads